# Finding the sum of the set of columns with non zero values in each row

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, correlation

I have a table where I have scraped each PGA tournament and the count of the number of times a player finished in the top 30. Example:

| Event | Marc Leishman | Patrick Rodgers | Scott Stallings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AT&T Pebble Beach Pro-Am | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| Barbasol Championship | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The goal for me is to find how each event correlates to other events in the table, using the number of players with a non zero value below as my measurement.  So the more players who have a non-zero value across the two events, the more correlation exists.

To accomplish this, It seems I have to go row by row (event AT&T Pebble 1st), find all columns > 0 (Patrick Rodgers and Scott Stallings)  and sum those columns only, ignoring the marc leishman column. And then sum values in each row.

There are about 200 columns and 100 rows in this google sheet, yet I have to repeat this same process for each row, since there will be distinct results for each event. The results would look like this:

| Event | Total |
| --- | --- |
| AT&T Pebble Beach Pro-Am | 6 |
| Barbasol Championship | 7 |

I was researching arrayformula to accomlish this but didnt see a way to have the row by row evaluation of columns in google sheets or excel. If there is a python solution to this problem, I'd be open to it too. Thanks for any guidance you can offer- and other approaches to finding the correlation between golf events would be welcome too.

Comment: definitely do-able! here's an empty sheet, paste the data you've got and I (or someone here) can help demo how to do it!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iue5ShJme0O-eX49G66gujhxRYBdyZH0k5imygPFAzE/edit

Comment: sorry for the delay but I have some sample data in there now. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Do the number values mean their "place" (1-30)? or how many times they won that tournament?

Comment: Those numbers in the sample data indicate how often they finished in the top 1-24 spots of the tournament.  My assumption being that if you finished that high in multiple tournaments, those tournaments likely play the same.
I also have less formatted data where I kept the full tournament standings (actual finish position as opposed to the count of top finishes) if a better approach arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a new tab on the sample sheet called MK_Idea.

First I just made a table of each pair of tournaments using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ROW('Build Sample Here'!A2:A)<TRANSPOSE(ROW('Build Sample Here'!A2:A)),'Build Sample Here'!A2:A&"|"&TRANSPOSE('Build Sample Here'!A2:A),)),"|",0,0),"where Col1<>'' and Col2<>''"))
```

Then I used an MMULT() around a two boolean VLOOKUP() statments multiplied against one another to sum up the number of columns/players) which both have values greater than 0 for that tournament.

This is that formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,MMULT(IFERROR((VLOOKUP(B2:B,'Build Sample Here'!A1:10000,COLUMN('Build Sample Here'!B1:1),0)>0)*(VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Build Sample Here'!A1:10000,COLUMN('Build Sample Here'!B1:1),0)>0),0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN('Build Sample Here'!B1:1)^0))))
```